# magento layout - content block structure and position

Tags: magento, layout

Here is a magento's newbie question.

Is there any way to see the content blocks of each magento theme, like for example in Joomla! where when typing "?tp=1" at the end of the url you can see the layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature in Magento which will allow you to view the structure of the layout including template file names (i.e. .phtml) and the associated block types.

This feature is very easy to enable in the admin area:

1. Log in to the admin area and go to system > configuration >
   developer.
2. Change the "Current Configuration Scope" setting in the top left of
   the screen.
3. After the page reloads you should see a tab titled 'Debug'.  Under
   this you have the option to display hints for both templates and
   blocks.  Change both to yes and visit the frontend.